# Oracle SQL PIVOT "Column ambigously defined"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to PIVOT the DOMAIN, PANEL SECTION and CATEGORY by MEASURE TYPE column.

Please check the image.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLjL8.png)

This is the code which I am running:

```
SELECT  ID,
        PERIOD,
        AMOUNT,
        "HOURS",
        "NUMBER",
        VALUE
 FROM 
    (select  a.ID,
            a.period, 
            b.domain,
            b.panel,
            b.section,
            b.category,
            b.MEASURE_TYPE,     
            a.value
        
    from TABLE_a a
    inner join TALBE_B b
    on a.ID = b.ID
    
)

PIVOT(
MAX("DOMAIN"),MAX("PANEL"),MAX("SECTION"),MAX("CATEGORY")
FOR MEASURE_TYPE IN ('Amount' AS "AMOUNT", 'Hours' AS "HOURS", 'Number' AS "NUMBER"))
```

It is giving me this error:

> ```
> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
> 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 4 Column: 9
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find conditional aggregation simpler to get working and more flexible.  I think you want:

```
select b.DOMAIN, b.PANEL, b.SECTION, b.CATEGORY,
       max(case when measure_type = 'Number' then value end) as number,
       max(case when measure_type = 'Hours' then value end) as hours,
       max(case when measure_type = 'Amount' then value end) as amount
from TABLE_a a join
     TALBE_B b
     on a.ID = b.ID
group by DOMAIN, PANEL, SECTION, CATEGORY
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select *` in `pivot` query and everything will be done by oracle as follows:

```
SELECT  *
 FROM 
    (select a.ID,
            a.period, 
            b.domain,
            b.panel,
            b.section,
            b.category,
            b.MEASURE_TYPE,     
            a.value      
    from TABLE_a a
    inner join TALBE_B b
    on a.ID = b.ID   )
PIVOT(
MAX("DOMAIN"),MAX("PANEL"),MAX("SECTION"),MAX("CATEGORY")
FOR MEASURE_TYPE IN ('Amount' AS "AMOUNT", 'Hours' AS "HOURS", 'Number' AS "NUMBER"))
```